# Need Regex help: It should not be start with numeric

Tags: regex, extjs

I tried the following  regex which is not working fine for the desired outcome:

```
^[A-Za-z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

The following should be allowed/not allowed:

```
Allowed: Number132 | N132 |Number Format
Not Allowed: 123Number | 1Number
```

Comment: Which programming language are you using? You could come up with `^\D+`

Comment: Works fine on a regex tester I found: http://www.regexpal.com/  I suspect your regex isn't actually the problem. I suspect something is going wrong with how you're calling it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `^\D+` if your regex engine supports it.
Another way to say the same would be: `^[^0-9]+`.

---

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/wX1zA8/1).

Answer (score 0):

`Number Format` has a space, which your regex isn't looking for. Could that be your trouble?

And what output are you seeing? Is it behaving correctly for anything?

Comment: Sorry Without space I need 
John123  like this i need

Comment: I would expect that regex to behave as you want, then. The problem might not be in the regex. What language are you using? What does the surrounding code look like?

Comment: in Ext JS , I need

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are looking for is MaskRe?
Maskre is for stopping input
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-maskRe
Regex is for when extjs is doing validations
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-regex